# MVC: Application has no errors but returns a blank page in IE

Tags: asp.net-mvc, build

*Sorry if this is not too specific. I could not make it more specific as I do not understand the issue*

I have an MVC application which ran well, and was I even published it. After modifying it, when I try to run it on my local, I get the following error in Chrome: `Server error. The webpage at http://localhost:63178 is currently unavailable. It may be overloaded or down for maintainance.` and IE returns a blank page

I even tried to return `Content("test")` on the index controller but to no avail.

There is no error in the code, but I just cannot get it to run. Other application projects work fine.

I have tried putting a break point in the Application_Start but the break points is never hit.

Other projects work fine, but this one.

**EDIT**:
Here is the system.web section of the web.config

```
<system.web>
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>
<pages>
    <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
    </namespaces>
</pages>
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
<profile defaultProvider="DefaultProfileProvider">
    <providers>
        <add name="DefaultProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultProfileProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationName="/" />
    </providers>
</profile>
<membership defaultProvider="DefaultMembershipProvider">
    <providers>
        <add name="DefaultMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultMembershipProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="/" />
    </providers>
</membership>
<roleManager defaultProvider="DefaultRoleProvider">
    <providers>
        <add name="DefaultRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultRoleProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationName="/" />
    </providers>
</roleManager>
<sessionState mode="InProc" customProvider="DefaultSessionProvider">
    <providers>
        <add name="DefaultSessionProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultSessionStateProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" />
    </providers>
</sessionState>
```

Comment: Sounds like you might have an infinite loop somewhere, perhaps a redirect loop.  Look into the code you modified - you can also look into you IIS settings.

Comment: I undid all the changed but that did not solve things

Comment: Try putting `Debugger.Launch(); Debugger.Break();` in your `Application_Start()` and see if you can get into the debugger that way.  These are in the `System.Diagnostics` namespace.

Comment: still not getting the debugger

Comment: Shot in the dark, but I get that error when my ASP.NET Development Server web service is busy crashing and burning (which happens to me more often than I'd like). Any idea if your ASP.NET Development Server is having an issues?

Comment: i am using my local iis and other applications (also using iis) work fine. The same issue happens when I switch to the development server

Comment: In VS disable "Just My Code" in "Debugging" section of options, attach to IIS, then click pause, then look at the stack trace. This may give you a hint about where the problem is. probably your site fails to load a dll, or fails to compile in a place where failing just disconnects clients (browser). You can also use "Fusion Log Viewer" to look at binding failures

Comment: gives me the error: A first chance exception of type 'System.Web.HttpException' occurred in System.Web.dll and when I try continuing, i again get a blan page

Comment: Since web server issues were ruled out by changing IIS to Visual Studio Development server, problem might be in your `web.config` `system.web` section. Could you share it?

Comment: This type of problem is hard to pinpoint without having access to the code.  You will need to find a break point that you can reach and then step from there till you find the problem.  First step is to check the things you changed before the problem occurred and roll those back. If you don't use version control, this should be a good explanation of why you should.

Comment: @jpo I don't think this error comes from IIS or Visual Studio development server. Please enable developer tools of Chrome, go to Network tab, request your application page and share the `Response header` of first get request.

Comment: When I had this issue recently, it was due to a `HttpHandler` that was throwing an exception. I don't see any of those in your `<system.web>`, but might you be on IIS7 and then that would be configured in `<system.webServer>`?

Comment: @Michael_B I did try that, but no avail. -kambiz, all i get is error 503. Service unavailable.-jeffesp, yes my local iis is ver 7. What I can configure this then. All other application are working fine though

Comment: can you paste your routes from the global.asax? Do you package all dependecies when you publish your application as package ?

Comment: Check your Windows event log. Look for entries with "ASP.NET [version]" as the source. This often helps gain more insight

Comment: @varun I am not publishing yet. I have not changed my routes. It's the default route

Comment: For future reference, make sure there's no app_offline.htm file hanging around.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem when running it on the local host when debugging the website. For me the solutions was to check the SQL login details.(The password had expired).[SQL Password expired](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zFUh0.png)